# Limit recent files to specific folder(s)

Tags: finder, search

The recent files section is showing many system files, how can it be cleaned up?

[image]

Here's my current search criteria

[image]

I couldn't limit it to specific folders

Here's what I tried so far. I couldn't find a variable which represents the full path.

[image]

Which property contains the full path?

Comment: Well of course they are going to show up as this is a specific search query you have setup. This is not the same as the Finder's own Recents. Indeed, that is called `Recents`, not `Recent files`. You will need to clarify what you are asking and try to focus on one question.

Comment: There is no searchable file path property offered by Finder. However, you might be able to narrow those results further in a way that may partially help you using other criteria such as those mentioned [in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/449009/359458) to another search question on this site.

Comment: To exclude system files, add this search criterion: System files aren't included

Comment: HoudahSpot (which uses the spotlight index) will search specific folders.

Comment: @Alper thanks for clarifying. A `fullpath` `begins with` would've been great here, bummer! Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Gilby Thank you, I wanted to find a solution within finder because I use recent file in open file dialogs especially

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1747483/limit-recent-files-to-specific-folder-macos

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, my bad!

Comment: Did you look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317401/spotlight-search-by-full-path which covers Raw Query & mdfind?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll check it, it looks promising, thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the folder you want to be the target.
2. Create a New search from there.

The location will be shown above the search criteria.

[image]

Comment: I need to pick several folders, that's why this solution is not ideal for me

Comment: It seems that you are suggesting going into a specific folder to include it in the search. What if there are folders to be searched that is not within that folder? Do you suggest the OP owner go into each and every of them and repeat the search?

Comment: @Alper The question is fairly broad and doesn't explicitly say that.

Comment: @unloco Can you describe you use case in a bit more detail? How many files are you modifying 'recently', outside of system files, for which you need separate search areas?

Comment: The title of the post is "Limit recent files to specific folder(s)" which implies multiple folders and it is quite reasonable to assume that they may not be all under one folder other than a high level one such as "Documents".